# Handle exceptions in VB.net and WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, error-handling

I am having a hard time to create an exception handler in a WPF application coded in VB.net. 
I already read a tons of articles on the internet, but most of them only work in WindowsForms or are written in C#. 
The thing I like is a simple MessageBox with the crash reason when the application is crashing. 
I think this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a02k5s0(v=vs.90).aspx)
should be the way to go, but I cannot get it to work, since it seems to be for Windows Forms.
Visual Studio show multiple errors, mainly because it is not finding the UnhandledException event...
I would be really grateful about an explanation how to get the think I try to get.

Edit: Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2949/Managing-Unhandled-Exceptions-in-NET)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications) and [this](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/07/unhandled-exception-handler-for-wpf.html). It should point you in the right direction...

Comment: Thanks! That really help, got it working with the tips in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event.

In `App.xaml` you need to add a handler for this event:

```
<Application DispatcherUnhandledException="DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler" .../>
```

Then in code behind you can write your code for handling the exception:

```
Private Sub App_DispatcherUnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    ' Process unhandled exception
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) you can find more information, even with sample code in Visual Basic.